# When freezing rain brings down power lines, is it usually because the power lines have too little slack?

Tags: structural-engineering

I did the math and figured out that according to the laws of physics, for any specific type of wire between poles a given distance apart, the more slack the wire has, the less its weight between those two poles gets magnified into tension force. When there's a buildup of ice on the wire and the wire has very little slack, the weight of the ice is already a lot heavier than the wire but the weight of the ice also gets greatly magnified into a force of tension that's much bigger than the weight of the ice on the part between those two poles. My question is

Did most of the places where part of a power line that fell down during a freezing rain storm fell down only from the weight of the ice on the power lines and not from a tree branch that fell down from a buildup of ice on it bringing down a power line with it? If so, did most of the spots where part of a power line fell down only from the weight of the ice on it have very little slack?

If so, this fact might be so useful for research. Maybe in the future, power lines could be built with more slack to account for the possibility that so much ice might build up on them during a freezing rain storm.

Comment: Why not increase the slack so the cable lays on the ground - that would reduce the weight even more....

Comment: Have you looked at the literature? Google Scholar, for example, can point you to hundreds of research studies on icing of catenaries, including optimum geometry, stochastic analysis, and mitigation measures. More slack requires higher poles and more wire—a substantial penalty to consider in conjunction with the likelihood and potential damage of icing. One alternative is to heat the wire.

Answer (score 1):

Slack means length of wire is longer than the distance between the towers, means more ice accumulation: more weight. I don't know what kind of calculation you did. I'd say you managed to get the exact wrong answer.

The geometry of a wire or cable suspended between the supports under self weight, meaning not supporting a bridge or deck, is a catenary. the span and slack and tension in the wires are highly standard and optimised for many factors, only a sub section of it is elements, wind, icing, earthquake, thunder, dynamic vibration and resonance in gusty storms, etc.

There is always room for improvement, but that shouldn't start with wrong assumptions.

**Edit**

After some comments by OP, I think this will help.

Let's call the sag in the wire S and the distance at post or tower between the insulators X. Under certain wind condition the wires will vibrate and swing around the insulators possibly into a paraboloidal kind of surface.

At no moment these individual surfaces shouldn't get closer than is likely to touch or even close enough to create an electrical arc and start a fire. This mean one restriction for the sag, 2*S < X+ arcing distance. This is just one of concerns

Comment: A gear system can be used to enable a person to life much heavier weights than they normally can. I've seen poles not very far apart with wires on them and the amount they were hanging down was a very small fraction of the height of those wires. I think they could have been made with more slack than that without causing a problem. I think that when they have that little slack, the system is like a gear system making the force of tension in the part of the wire between those two poles much greater than the weight of the wire. You're technically correct that the more slack, the more weight of

Comment: ice during a freezing rain storm. However, I think that when there's that little slack, the weight gets magnified into tension by a larger factor. I don't think your answer solves my problem.

Comment: @Timothy, as I said in my answer, the standards for electrical transportation on aluminum or coper cables have been studied in depth with consideration to many aspects of structural, electrical, electromagnetic, radio frequency emitions, spark control at insulators, etc. I would recommend couple of references, but before anything I encourage you to brush up on high school math  and trig specially hyperbolic trig, to be able to benefit from free material on the subject. BTW our answers are to point to correct solution not affirmation of wrong hypothesis.

Comment: Maybe your answer is good and I just don't fully understand it. I actually got high marks in a lot of math courses in in high school and university and then got a book prize for getting such high marks in math when I graduated from university. I realize that doesn't mean I know everything in math. I struggled to understand what the textbook for my differential equations course and needed help from my professor to understand it because the book wasn't written clearly. I suppose some really good math experts unlike me probably could have figured out some math statements entirely mathematically

Comment: that were related to what they read in the book as a result of seeing what the book said. I don't think that was one of the math courses that I did so well in. The equations for a hanging chain actually weren't taught at all in any math course I took. In grade 12 Physics, I think I might have had homework problems involving a weightless string with things pulling on different parts of it. The equations for a hanging chain might be more complicated because we don't neglect its weight. I'm pretty sure that if you pull on a chain with one fixed end, the harder you pull, the less curved it will

Comment: be. A chain is composed of separate links. When a chain is hanging in a parabola, the link closest to the bottom must have its weight balanced by the sum of the forces the two links beside it are exerting on it. The closer the direction of the forces those two links are exerting on it to being in opposite directions, the larger their magnitude must be for their vector sum to be equal and opposite to the gravitational force on that link.

Comment: @Timothy, the curve is not parabolic, it's catenary, regardless, what I am about to say applies. Let's call the sag in the wire S and the distance at post or tower between the insulators X. Under certain wind condition the wires will vibrate and swing around the insulators possibly into a paraboloidal kind of surface. At no moment these individual surfaces shouldn't get closer than is likely to touch or even create an  electriccal arc and start a fire. This mean one restriction for the sag, S < X+ arcing. This is just one of concerns.

Comment: @Timothy there is a lot of material about how cables, wires, chains etc hang and you should check some of it out. One possible link : https://www.quora.com/Why-do-electrical-overhead-wires-hang-loosely-instead-of-being-stretched-tightly

Comment: @kamran You're right. After what you wrote I figured out that the stable shape of a hanging chain really is not the same shape as a parabola. That's probably why it's given another name "catenay". I'm not sure where I got the idea that it was a parabola from. I never thought twice about trying to figure out whether its shape really is a parabola. Maybe I got the idea from the shape defined to satisfy so many other properties being a parabola. A parabolic mirror can focus straight rays into a point. I heard on TV about a mercury telescope and checked that the math actually does predict that a

Comment: spinning liquid takes the shape of a parabola, the very shape that focuses straight rays into a point. The Dufferin gate to the Canadian National Exhibition appeared to be a parabola. Maybe either I didn't notice the difference or it really was built into a parabola by mistake and by luck, it didn't fall apart despite having some transverse stress. For it to be a parabola without transverse stress, it would have to be thicker at the top but I think it's actually thinner there.